# How to set shared home for JIRA Data Center when it is installed using Helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, jira, kubernetes-helm

I installed JIRA Data Center helm chart and had the k8s provision the shared home dynamically by setting the create flag to true as shown in this link.

https://github.com/atlassian/data-center-helm-charts/blob/main/src/main/charts/jira/values.yaml#L219

This created the AWS EFS access point as expected. Also, the pod shows "JIRA_SHARED_HOME" environment variable for Jira container. However, the JIRA software doesn't seem to honor the environment variable. The log (/var/atlassian/jira/logs/atlassian-jira.log) shows that jira.shared.home is set to the same values as jira.local.home which is /var/atlassian/application-data/jira.

I expected the jira.shared.home to be set as /var/atlassian/application-data/shared-home as the below link would indicate.

https://github.com/atlassian/data-center-helm-charts/blob/main/src/main/charts/jira/values.yaml#L249

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround based on the following documentation which necessitates the cluster.properties file in the Jira local home.

https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/configuring-a-jira-cluster/#jira-setup

The helm chart allows creation of config/properties file from k8s config maps.

https://github.com/atlassian/data-center-helm-charts/blob/main/src/main/charts/jira/values.yaml#L765

Create a ConfigMap k8s object

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: jira-configs
data:
  cluster.properties: |
    jira.shared.home=/var/atlassian/application-data/shared-home
```

Add the following to the JIRA data center helm chart values.yaml.

```
additionalFiles:
  - name: jira-configs
    type: configMap
    key: cluster.properties
    mountPath: /var/atlassian/application-data/jira
```